# How to use if else with for loop in jinja2?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, flask, jinja2

I want to use a if else statement in combination with a for loop in Jinja2. In Python my code works perfectly, but in Jinja2 I can't get it to work.

My Python code looks as follow:

```
if parsed['links']['next'] is not 'null':
                url = 'https://'+ shopnaam + '.webshop.com/admin/products' + parsed['links']['next']
                time.sleep(2)
                for product in parsed['products']:
                    print (product['id'], product['nl']['title'])
            else:
                break
```

My Jinja2 code is as follow:

```
{% if parsed['links']['next'] is defined %}
    {{url}} is 'https://'+ shopnaam +'.webshop.com/admin/products' + {{parsed['links']['next']}}    
    {% for product in parsed['products'] %}
    <TR>
    <TD  width="100px" >{{product['id']}}</TD>
    <TD  width="300px" >{{product['nl']['title']}}</TD>
    <TD  width="150px">{{product['price_excl']}}</TD>
    <TD  width="150px">{{product['price_incl']}}</TD>
    <TD  width="300px">{{product['created_at']}}</TD>
    </TR>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

I want to get pagination  working in  Jinja2 , now it only retrieves the first 50 products only on the first product. But the json page has 70 pages.

My JSON data looks like this:

```
products: [
{
article_code: "123",
barcode: "456",
brand_id: 2600822,
created_at: "2018-05-31T15:15:34+02:00",
data01: "",
data02: "",
data03: "",
delivery_date_id: null,
has_custom_fields: false,
has_discounts: false,
has_matrix: false,
hits: 0,
hs_code: null,
id: 72660113,
image_id: null,
is_visible: false,
price_excl: 33.0165,
price_incl: 39.95,
price_old_excl: 0,
price_old_incl: 0,
product_set_id: null,
product_type_id: null,
search_context: "123 456 789",
shop_id: 252449,
sku: "789",
supplier_id: 555236,
updated_at: "2018-05-31T15:15:34+02:00",
variants_count: 1,
visibility: "hidden",
weight: 0,
nl: {
content: "",
fulltitle: "Grid Lifter",
slug: "grid-lifter",
title: "Grid Lifter"
}
],

links: {
first: ".json",
last: ".json?page=70",
prev: null,
next: ".json?page=2",
count: 3497,
limit: 50,
pages: 70
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `set` in your Jinja2 code to set a variable:

```
{% if parsed['links']['next'] %}
    {% set next = parsed['links']['next'] %}
    {% set url = 'https://'+ shopnaam +'.webshop.com/admin/products' + next %}
    {% for product in parsed['products'] %}
        <tr>
            <td  width="100px" >{{product['id']}}</td>
            <td  width="300px" >{{product['nl']['title']}}</td>
            <td  width="150px">{{product['price_excl']}}</td>
            <td  width="150px">{{product['price_incl']}}</td>
            <td  width="300px">{{product['created_at']}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

but I can't see a place where you use it in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I am kinda getting somewhere now. Tried your code, and now I get the following: TypeError: must be str, not dict. I retrieve all this data from Python. 

This is what I return:

return render_template('producten.html',parsed = parsed, shopnaam = shopnaam, url = url)

Do you have any idea what could be the cause of this error?

Comment: @Solaiman Please make sure that: 1) `parsed` is 2D dictionary so this is valid string `parsed['links']['next']` and this is a list `parsed['products']` 2) `product` is a 2D dictionary so these are valid: `product['id']`, ..., `product['nl']['title']`

Comment: I have added a sample of the JSON format that I am retrieving with a get request.

Comment: @Solaiman ok, can you share a screenshot where I can see the error?

Comment: @Solaiman Try to replace `parsed['links']['next']` in `{% set url ....` string with `next` and initialize `next` above using `set`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: well the error is gone now, but only the first 50 values are showed. So pagination isn't working, do you have any clue how I could populate the table with all the data available? So also from the other pages.

Comment: @Solaiman this loop `{% for product in parsed['products'] %}` iterates over all elements in `parsed['products']` list so make sure number of elements in list is correct

Comment: yes that's correct, standard this list contains a maximum of  50 elements and the remaining elements are on the next page. So to reach the next elements I need to get to request a new URL. And to do this I wanted to use a if statement that checks parsed['links']['next']. I have added a screenshot for you to give you a better insight in how this json data actually looks. See https://ibb.co/nacQKo . I also really appreciate your help so far. Cause I have asked this question on another forum but so far no result regarding this matter.

Comment: @Solaiman yes, you need to make a request to another URL (that's the next page) to fetch more elements, but Jinja2 doesn't have this functionality, you need to implement this logic in your python code and pass it in `render_template` func or you can implement it using javascript on your page (via ajax requests for example). Both cases are okay. If my answer helped you a bit - please consider to mark it as an answer to you question.